# How to send signals between processes?

Tags: c, signals

So, i want to send signals between processes.

I want send a signal starting in a child1, catch by parentprocess and, after that, send the same signal to child process 2. When child 2 receive the signal, i want to send another signal back to parent child, and then parent child kill both child processes.

I have tried this:

```
new_pid = fork();
                        sleep(3);
                        switch(new_pid) {
                        case -1:
                                perror("fork failed");
                                exit(1);
                        case 0:
                                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                                sleep(3);
                                pause();
                                break;
                        default:
                                signal(SIGUSR1, trata_SIGSEGV);
                                sleep(3);
                                new_pid2 = fork();
                                sleep(3);
                                kill(new_pid2, SIGUSR1);
                                sleep(3);
                                switch(new_pid2) {
                                case -1:
                                        perror("fork failed");
                                case 0:
                                        signal(SIGUSR1, trata_SIGSEGV);
                                        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
                                        sleep(3);
                                        pause();
                                        break;
                                default:
                                        signal(SIGUSR2, trata_SIGSEGV);
                                        kill(new_pid, SIGKILL);
                                        kill(new_pid2, SIGKILL);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
```

Only parent child receive the signal, then nothing happens and go to program menu).

```
   void trata_SIGSEGV(int sig){

        if (sig == SIGUSR1) {
                printf("Received");
        }

        if (sig == SIGUSR2) {
                printf("Received");
        }

        if (sig == SIGINT) {
                printf("Received");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues going on here.  There may be more in trata_SIGSEGV.

1. You give no time after forking for the processes to set up to be ready for processing.  As you're sending default termination signals, it's likely they're killing the recipient before the recipient is listening for them.   (Are you thinking signal waits for a signal?  It doesn't; it merely configures what should be done if/when the signal happens.)
2. Line 19 is attempting to send the trata_SIGSEGV signal to process SIGUSR2.  That's not going to work.
3. You end with the problem you start with - the main execution thread has no delays in its processing from forking off the processes to telling the scheduler to simply end them.

On a modern computer, probably even a millisecond delay would be far more than enough time for the signal handlers to be set up.  But if you want them to happen reliably, you need to give at least *some* delay for the other processes to get where they need to be.

Alternatively, I think you could set up the signal handlers in the parent and then fork.

Given your update, I'm wondering how you know which process got what signal.  My suggestion for your signal handler:

```
void trata_SIGSEGV(int sig) {
    printf("%d received signal %d\n", getpid(), sig);
    if (SIGINT == sig) exit(1);
}
```

Also, I'm noticing you're sending the first signal to process 2 before checking what the fork return is, so process 2 is signalling itself before it can possibly have the signal handlers set up.  Set up the signal handlers before you do any forking, so there's no race there.  I've verified in my own test of your code that the signal handlers are retained across fork.

Comment: I have edited the post... Now i put some sleeps on code for waiting, but i didnt figure  the error yet.

Comment: You say "default ignored signals", but `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` terminate the process by default, do they not?  That's what it says for POSIX [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43) anyway (and the macOS `man 3 signal` page agrees).

Comment: Jonathan, that's exactly what was happening - I think I'm just so used to dealing with processes that have signal handlers for them I forgot about that.  After messing with this stuff for a couple of decades, I'm not always as quick to refresh my memory with the man pages as I should be.  :/